# Cache oblivious data structure with constant time random index insert/delete?

Tags: c, performance, list, data-structures, cpu-cache

**Lists** have constant-time insert/delete operations once you know the pointer of a list cell, but are not cache oblivious: two neighboring elements aren't always close in memory, and if you do do enough insertions/deletions, your heap will probably become a cache-disaster [pointer spaghetti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35091349/how-to-avoid-heap-pointer-spaghetti-in-dynamic-graphs).

**Arrays** are cache oblivious: two neighboring elements are always close together in memory, but inserting and deleting elements in arbitrary, random position is `O(N)` due to the need to rewrite the remaining array.

Is there any cache oblivious data structure with amortized constant time random index insertion and deletion?

Comment: I suspect this is impossible, because if it was possible, everyone would use this data structure all the time :-) You might look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure) though.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but maybe it is just not well known or researched enough yet? The concept of cache obliviousness is pretty new. I think the hard thing you are talking about is having a structure with random `O(1)` read and random `O(1)` insertion, but I don't have the read req... also, the heap doesn't help with the problem at all as it is not cache oblivious.

Comment: Have you looked at gapped arrays?  You leave gaps every N elements, so an insert only has to copy a fixed amount of data (amortized).  Also, a linked list doesn't have constant-time access/insert to the Nth element anyway.  Maybe you should be more clear about which operations you need, and the balance between them (e.g. read-mostly?)

Comment: I tried to find anything about arrays with gaps.  I've heard of this, but never looked into it.  Maybe there's a name for this that I'm forgetting.  The obvious problem is how to tell the difference between a gap and a used entry.  Efficient indexing requires extra bookkeeping anyway, or else you have to check every gap before the index you want.  Maybe a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure) is useful?

Comment: @PeterCordes lists have constant insert to the `nth` element once you know its pointer, which is what matter! My algorithm will be walking through the list linearly and removing/adding elements at arbitrary positions. Since the cursor will always know the pointer to the list cell, it is always O(1) to add/remove a cell. The only issue is lists aren't cache efficient.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm thinking in something like that, actually. I don't think a rope specifically is useful for my case, but it may be the case that the asymptotics of a Rope is exactly what I need. Perhaps something similar but not quite it. I'll keep thinking about it.